# remove previous element if next element exists with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Once again I'm hoping your joint expertise will help find an elegant solution. I'm automating a report to minimize human input (and error). The base of the report is a webpage, which has the following code:

```
</p></li>

 <li>ARTICLE 1<br />
    <p>    
       <div class="list">
           Nothing found. 
       </div>
    </p>
 </li>
 <li>
    <p>ARTICLE 2</p>    
    <div class="list">
    <h4 class="sub-heading">ITEMS</h4>
     <ul>
        <li class="item">
           <span class="title">
```

The p elements are created by me, while the div class="list" are outputs of a plugin beyond my reach. Basically the plugin scans the databases with certain query, and produces either a list of items found for given query or a "Nothing found" string. The operators then copypaste it to somewhere and remove the "ITEMS" header and "Nothing found." to make the report more readable.
What I managed to do so far is using these jqueries:

```
$(".list .sub-heading").addClass("hidden");
$(".list:contains('Nothing found.')").addClass("hidden");
```

What I would like to achieve is add a jquery, that removes not only the divs containing "Nothing found.", but also the preceeding element, which is the line containing "ARTICLE 1" in the above example.
Please assist if you could produce a reasonable solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does `$(".list:contains('Nothing found.')").addClass("hidden");` work correctly?

Comment: I was just making sure that wasn't part of this question you were asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can you `closest` method and hide the `li` element which hides all of it's content:

```
$(".list:contains('Nothing found.')").closest('li').addClass("hidden");
```

Comment: A bit more elegant than parent().parent() imo.

Comment: Accidentally put parent twice, I also added 'li' to parent so basically they are the same, the parent and closest function are almost identical.

Comment: @Pitchinnate `parent` only selects the first parent of an element, if you specify the selector it selects the first parent only if it matches the selector, as the parent element is `p` your selector doesn't select the element, actually your first answer was correct.

Comment: You're a genius.:) In fact I kinda screwed the question and I actually need to hide thos elements with found items, but I changed the "Nothing found." to "ITEMS" and it worked like a charm.

Comment: @undefined That is what I thought also but when I actually created a test page, `parent().parent()` actually hid the whole `<ul>`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this:

```
$(".list:contains('Nothing found.')").parent('li').addClass("hidden");
```